# Replace the last word of last command but keep the first

Tags: bash, command-history

Assuming I have a script for grepping through a bunch of files with certain options and run this script with many different words:

```
$ mygrep worda
[output]
$ mygrep wordb
[output]
$ mygrep wordc
[output]
```

I know `!$` is a placeholder for the last word of the last command. Is there a similar placeholder for the first word so I could save myself some typing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not `$!` but `!$` -- bash history expansions begin with the `!`.

The opposite of `!$`, the last argument, is `!^`, the first **argument**.

The previous **command** can be retrieved as `!:0`, not quite as easy to type as `!$`.

You can also do a search and replace with `^worda^wordb`. That is not **global** search&replace, it only replaces the first one found. Global search and replace is `!!:gs/worda/wordb`.

Phew. More info at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction

Comment: Three letters are two too many. Now I think it'll be more convenient to do something like `alias g=mygrep`, and then after I'm done with my searches do `unalias g` (or just log out.)

Comment: You could also use `Up-Arrow` followed by `Ctrl-W` to erase previous word (i.e. the last argument).